# Add two nodes as a Label Expression in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I could not able to add two nodes under "Label Expression" in Jenkins configuration.

My job has to run on both master node and one slave node simultaneously. But when i try to add the below expression in Jenkins job configuration -> Label Expression, it not accepting two nodes.
I am adding it in below way:

```
master && "My Slave"
```

Regards,
Rohith

Answer (score 0):

By default, jenkins doesn't support running single job on multiple nodes simultaneously.

Take a look at Multi Configuration job combined with https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Elastic+Axis plugin.